# Trying to bind gunicorn with django raises Timezone error

Tags: python, django, timezone, vps, gunicorn

```
    (blogenv)root@Blog:/opt/blogenv/blog/blog# gunicorn blog.wsgi:application --bind overthink.co
[2015-02-18 20:10:29 +0000] [25886] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.2.1
[2015-02-18 20:10:29 +0000] [25886] [INFO] Listening at: http://ip-address (25886)
[2015-02-18 20:10:29 +0000] [25886] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-02-18 20:10:29 +0000] [25891] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25891
[2015-02-18 20:10:29 +0000] [25891] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/opt/blogenv/blog/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 123, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: ASIA/NICOSIA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 503, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 116, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/opt/blogenv/blog/blog/blog/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/opt/blogenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 123, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: ASIA/NICOSIA
[2015-02-18 20:10:29 +0000] [25891] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 25891)
[2015-02-18 20:10:29 +0000] [25886] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2015-02-18 20:10:29 +0000] [25886] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
(blogenv)root@Blog:/opt/blogenv/blog/blog#
```

Notice that i have replaced my ip address. 
I am hosting on digital ocean on a Amsterdam located VPS. Is that the problem?
Also localy i used to use python3 not python2.

I have never deployed before and i struggle a lot since all the tutorials are outdated and most of the documentation is not clear.

Comment: there is no `'ASIA/NICOSIA'` timezone; there is only `'Asia/Nicosia'` (case-sensitive). Make sure there is no unnecessary `.upper()` call.

Comment: Thank you J.F.Sebastian!